# How can I define an object property that is in scope?

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting this reference error in my console. I don't see why instrument is not defined, or out of scope. While this setupSelectedInstrumentSelector() is inside the const app, there are other functions in this program that work fine with other querySelectors, consts, etc.

Uncaught ReferenceError: instrument is not defined

```
const selectedInstrumentSelector = document.querySelector('.instrument-selector');

const instrumentTuningPresets = {
    'Guitar (6 strings)': [4, 11, 7, 2, 9, 4],
    'Guitar (7 strings)': [11, 4, 7, 2, 9, 4],
    'Bass (4 strings)': [7,2,9,4],
    'Bass (5 strings)': [7, 2, 9, 4, 11]
};


setupSelectedInstrumentSelector() {
        for(instrument in instrumentTuningPresets) {
            let instrumentOption = tools.createElement('option', instrument);
            selectedInstrumentSelector.appendChild(instrumentOption);
        }
    },
```

Comment: try `for(let instrument in instrumentTuningPresets)`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#syntax

Comment: So what logs when you console.log(instrument) within the loop also what logs when you console.log(instrumentOption) after it is declared, finally where does tools come from and what is it?

Answer (score 0):

add  or define variable let or const in for loop
`for(let instrument in instrumentTuningPresets)`